# Can't get field value from parsed JSON

Tags: arrays, json

This is my Ajax call ,

```
  let options = {};
  options.chaincodeId = "instrumentcc";
  options.methodToBeCalled = "queryInstrument";
  let arguments = {};
  arguments.arg1 = '{"selector":{"Status":"open"}}';
  options.dataArguments = arguments;
  console.log("options ", options)
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/postSender",
    datatype: "JSON",
    type: "Post",
    data: options,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("data ", data)
      data1 = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log("data parse", data1)
      } 
  });
```

Response Data  is

```js
[{"Key":"1088b94e1f5353484ff9609cbeef8cd36679e1af145e273140c65d96a7e24b07",
  "Record":{
            "docType":"InstruObject",
            "RefNo":"I001",
            "Date":"2018-11-15T00:00:00Z",
            "SellerID":"B002",
            "BuyerID":"B001",
            "Amount":"1000",
            "Status":"open",
            "DueDate":"2019-11-16T00:00:00Z",
            "ProgramID":"1prg",
            "PPRID":"1ppr",
            "UploadBatchNo":"323453454121",
            "ValueDate":"2019-01-04T12:43:59Z"
          }
}]
```

I need to get the `RefNo` from `Record` .
I used `data1.Record.RefNo` , it show data1.Record is undefined.
How can I access `RefNo` then?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to add 'data1 = JSON.parse(data);' data is already parsed... so you can directly write data[0].Record.RefNo .. data[0] as data is array not an object

Comment: without parsing data  it is undefined for data[0].Record.RefNo.      after parsing i could get my RefNo .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log(data[0].Record.RefNo); without JSON.parse.